# Getting all the info from many normalized tables that are related to a single table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called Word which has 8 related and normalized tables that have a foreign key to Word's id.

- Word

  - id
  - value
- misc

  - id
  - fk
  - value
- antonyms

  - id
  - fk
  - value
- example

  - id
  - fk
  - value
- partofspeech

  - id
  - fk
  - value
- languageoforigin

  - id
  - fk
  - value
- definition

  - id
  - fk
  - value
- pronunciation

  - id
  - fk
  - value
- synonym

  - id
  - fk
  - value

What is the best way to get all of the information? At first I was thinking to LEFT OUTER JOIN all the tables together but the potential number of rows would be the number of rows of each table multiplied together which is an exponentially high number. Should each table be queried separately using Word.id or is there an sql statement that would work great for this situation?

EDIT: added fields, all the foreign keys point to Word.id

Comment: Kindly put all the fields of your tables so we can easily help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you do not want to use an outer join in this situation because of a potential of combinatorial explosion. Making multiple queries, however, would result in eight round-trips, which is not ideal either.

To avoid multiple round-trips, you can make a denormalized query with `UNION ALL`, like this:

```
SELECT
    value as word
,   NULL AS antonym_id, NULL AS antonym
,   NULL AS synonym_id, NULL as synonym
,   ... -- add more columns here
FROM word WHERE id=@id
        UNION ALL
SELECT
    NULL as word
,   id AS antonym_id, value AS antonym
,   NULL AS synonym_id, NULL as synonym
,   ... -- add more columns here
FROM antonym WHERE fk=@id
        UNION ALL
SELECT
    NULL as word
,   NULL AS antonym_id, NULL AS antonym
,   id AS synonym_id, value as synonym
,   ... -- add more columns here
FROM synonym WHERE fk=@id
```

Note how each table supplies a range of columns for the result, and pads the remaining columns with `NULL`s: `word` table supplies the `word` column, `antonym` supplies `antonym_id` and `antonym`, `synonym` supplies `synonym_id` and `synonym`, and so on.

You can read this result set into an object with multiple attached lists by making a single round-trip to your RDBMS, and checking the columns supplied by each row for non-null values in the corresponding columns. For example, when you see a non-null `synonym_id` column, you know that the row represents the `synonym` table.

Comment: Would it at all be better to use "value as word" for every select statement (getting rid of antonym, synonym columns and leaving the id columns to identify the value type of word), thereby reducing the number of columns by the number of tables-1? Or is that kind of optimization not needed since the extra columns are used just for clarity ?(I'm not sure if reducing the columns will improve performance)

Comment: And to look up all the information for a word, I would first have to look up the word in the Word table, store that id in a variable, then use that id in this query or is there a way to look up a word without the separate query that retrieves the id?

Comment: Also if there were fewer tables (say 3 or 4 related tables) would it be better to LEFT JOIN instead of using UNION ALL? (in retrieving the information for a word (some words may not have supplementary data)
If not, then when would someone choose to use LEFT JOIN instead of this way of using UNION ALL?

Comment: @user2807904 In this particular case reducing column count is not going to give you much performance boost, because most columns in most rows would be `null` anyway, so their transfer is going to be cheap. You do not have to do a roundtrip to get the `ID` - you can join to `word` in each query, restrict by `w.id=dependent.id`, and discard the columns from `word`. It is not the number of tables that matter, it's the number of rows in each one. If you have one-to-one relationship to 100 tables, you would still get one row. If you have one-to-many with ten rows in two tables, you get 100 rows.

Comment: Is it possible to store the ID after the first select is executed so that the id variable can then be used for the subsequent queries instead of doing a join for every select?

Comment: @user2807904 No, `UNION ALL` queries are unrelated to each other. However, you shouldn't worry about it, because any RDBMS worth its money is going to do exactly what you suggest - run a single query, store the ID, and use it in all other queries. You wouldn't get any performance penalty for it.

Comment: It seems sqlite cannot store variables so I may need a first select query anyway. Store the value in a variable in Go (the language I'm using), and run this answer as the second query. Would you know if between doing this or a join on every select statement which would be better? I'll try this both ways I suppose and see how it goes.